# Distribute an iOS app on the Apple Store for a company

Tags: ios, mobile

I developed an Android/iOS app for a customer, a small company. The company wants to distribute the app on Google Play and on the Apple Store. Google Play is already sorted: a gmail account, $25 one time fee and that's it. On the Apple Store what I have to do? The company wants to distribute the app on its own name (not mine) and it's going to pay whatever subscription is required. The app must be publicly available on the store so it's not an "in-house" app. They don't have any Mac product (no iPad, no iPhones, no MacBooks etc..). I have a Mac, X-code and an Apple Id (I developed the iOS app on my machine) but I'm not enrolled in the Apple Developer program (I could do it, if required).

What I need to do exactly to get the iOS app into the Apple Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's the company that's going to distribute the app, they need to join the [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/whats-included/) and add you to their development team. They'll need to create development and distribution certificates as well as set up an iTunes App Store account. The page I linked above as well as the [How the Program Works](https://developer.apple.com/programs/how-it-works/) page should get you started.

Comment: Ok thanks, but should I enroll the company owner as an individual or as an organization? My fear is to get stuck at some point. For example, if I enroll the company as an individual will it be possible for them to add me on their developer "team"?

Comment: Enroll them as a company so that they can add you to their team. In fact, you'll probably need them to walk through the process with you. The team agent needs to be someone who has the authority to accept an agreement on the company's behalf, which probably isn't you, and you'll need certain other information, like the company's DUNS number, to which you might not have easy access.